# java + Consuming a SOAP web service + "Two classes Have the same XML type name ..."

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm trying to consume a soap web service with java.

I have classes generated by "wsimport" the following WSDL:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="RepositorioXDS" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="adocumentrepository_servicesService" targetNamespace="RepositorioXDS">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" xmlns:ns1="RepositorioXDS" targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" version="1.0">

  <xs:import namespace="RepositorioXDS"/>

  <xs:element name="RegistryErrorList" type="tns:RegistryErrorList"/>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="RegistryErrorList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="ns1:RegistryError"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="highestSeverity" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="RegistryError">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="codeContext" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="errorCode" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="location" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="severity" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:ns1="RepositorioXDS" targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" version="1.0">

  <xs:import namespace="RepositorioXDS"/>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="AssociationType1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Slot" type="tns:SlotType1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="associationType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="home" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lid" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="objectType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="sourceObject" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="targetObject" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="SlotType1">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="slotType" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="ClassificationType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="tns:LocalizedStringType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Slot" type="tns:SlotType1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="classificationNode" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="classificationScheme" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="classifiedObject" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="home" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lid" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="nodeRepresentation" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="objectType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="LocalizedStringType">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="charset" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="ExternalIdentifierType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="tns:LocalizedStringType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="home" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="identificationScheme" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lid" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="objectType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="registryObject" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" version="1.0">

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="RetrieveDocumentSetRequestType.DocumentRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="DocumentUniqueId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="HomeCommunityId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="RepositoryUniqueId" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType.DocumentResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="Document" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="DocumentUniqueId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="HomeCommunityId" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="mimeType" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="RepositoryUniqueId" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="RepositorioXDS" xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" xmlns:ns1="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="RepositorioXDS" version="1.0">

  <xs:import namespace="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007"/>

  <xs:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0"/>

  <xs:import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rs:3.0"/>

  <xs:element name="AssociationType1" type="ns2:AssociationType1"/>

  <xs:element name="ClassificationType" type="ns2:ClassificationType"/>

  <xs:element name="DocumentType" type="tns:DocumentType"/>

  <xs:element name="DocumentsRequest" type="tns:DocumentsRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="ExternalIdentifierType" type="ns2:ExternalIdentifierType"/>

  <xs:element name="ExtrinsicObjectType" type="tns:ExtrinsicObjectType"/>

  <xs:element name="LocalizedStringType" type="ns2:LocalizedStringType"/>

  <xs:element name="PING" type="tns:PING"/>

  <xs:element name="PINGResponse" type="tns:PINGResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET" type="tns:PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET"/>

  <xs:element name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse" type="tns:PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET" type="tns:RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET"/>

  <xs:element name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse" type="tns:RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="RegistryError" type="ns3:RegistryError"/>

  <xs:element name="RegistryErrorList" type="ns3:RegistryErrorList"/>

  <xs:element name="RegistryPackageType" type="tns:RegistryPackageType"/>

  <xs:element name="RegistryResponseType" type="tns:RegistryResponseType"/>

  <xs:element name="RetrieveDocumentSetRequestType.DocumentRequest" type="ns1:RetrieveDocumentSetRequestType.DocumentRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType.DocumentResponse" type="ns1:RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType.DocumentResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="SlotType1" type="ns2:SlotType1"/>

  <xs:element name="SubmitObjectsRequest" type="tns:SubmitObjectsRequest"/>

  <xs:element name="SubmitObjectsRequest.RegistryObjectList" type="tns:SubmitObjectsRequest.RegistryObjectList"/>

  <xs:complexType name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Retrievedocumentsetrequest" type="ns1:RetrieveDocumentSetRequestType.DocumentRequest"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Retrievedocumentsetresponse" type="ns1:RetrieveDocumentSetResponseType.DocumentResponse"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Submitobjectsrequest" type="tns:SubmitObjectsRequest"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Documentsrequest" type="tns:DocumentsRequest"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="SubmitObjectsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RegistryObjectList" type="tns:SubmitObjectsRequest.RegistryObjectList"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="comment" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="SubmitObjectsRequest.RegistryObjectList">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Association" type="ns2:AssociationType1"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Classification" type="ns2:ClassificationType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ExtrinsicObject" type="tns:ExtrinsicObjectType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="RegistryPackage" type="tns:RegistryPackageType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>





  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="ExtrinsicObjectType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Classification" type="ns2:ClassificationType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Description" type="ns2:LocalizedStringType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ExternalIdentifier" type="ns2:ExternalIdentifierType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="ns2:LocalizedStringType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Slot" type="ns2:SlotType1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="home" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="isOpaque" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lid" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="mimeType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="objectType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>


  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="RegistryPackageType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Classification" type="ns2:ClassificationType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="ExternalIdentifier" type="ns2:ExternalIdentifierType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="LocalizedString" type="ns2:LocalizedStringType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="ns2:LocalizedStringType"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Slot" type="ns2:SlotType1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="home" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="lid" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="objectType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="DocumentsRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Document" type="tns:DocumentType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="dummy" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="DocumentType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Registryresponse" type="tns:RegistryResponseType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="RegistryResponseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="tns:RegistryErrorList"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Slot" type="ns2:SlotType1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="requestId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="status" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>



  <xs:complexType name="PING">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="PINGResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Pingresult" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PINGResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:PINGResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="PING">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:PING" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="adocumentrepository">
    <wsdl:operation name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET" name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse" name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET" name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse" name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PING">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:PING" name="PING">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:PINGResponse" name="PINGResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="adocumentrepository_servicesServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:adocumentrepository">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="PING">
      <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="PING">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="PINGResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="adocumentrepository_servicesService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:adocumentrepository_servicesServiceSoapBinding" name="adocumentrepositoryPort">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.42:8330/RepositorioXDS/adocumentrepository_services"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'm initializing the service as follows:

```
QName qName = new QName("RepositorioXDS", "adocumentrepository_servicesService");
URL url = new URL("file:///opt/adocumentrepository_services.xml");
AdocumentrepositoryServicesService service = new AdocumentrepositoryServicesService(url, qName);
Adocumentrepository port = service.getAdocumentrepositoryPort();
```

when making `service.getAdocumentrepositoryPort()` I am getting the following exepcion:

```
...    
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 6 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "{RepositorioXDS}RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET
        at public simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory.createRETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET()
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at repositorioxds.RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSET
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "{RepositorioXDS}RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse
        at public simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory.createRETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse()
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at repositorioxds.RETRIEVEDOCUMENTSETResponse
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "{RepositorioXDS}PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET
        at public simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory.createPROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET()
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at repositorioxds.PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSET
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "{RepositorioXDS}PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory.createPROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse(simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse)
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at repositorioxds.PROVIDEANDREGISTERDOCUMENTSETResponse
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "{RepositorioXDS}PING". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PING
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory.createPING(simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PING)
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at repositorioxds.PING
Hay dos clases que tienen el mismo nombre de tipo XML "{RepositorioXDS}PINGResponse". Utilice @XmlType.name y @XmlType.namespace para asignarles nombres diferentes.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PINGResponse
        at public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory.createPINGResponse(simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.PINGResponse)
        at simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds.ObjectFactory
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at repositorioxds.PINGResponse
...
```

I searched @XmlType with the same name in the generated classes, but I have not found. Really I appreciate any advice

Comment: Do you have a leftover package 'simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds` from some earlier effort? (I don't see this namespace emerging from the XML Schema statements in the WSDL you have posted up front - there the namespace is just RepositorioXDS, resulting in package repositorioxds.) - If there is, remove and build again, from scratch.

Comment: The "Utilice @XmlType ..." (i.e., "Use..." if my Spanish is good enough ;-) ) means that you should *add* such annotations to the Java code, which is pretty useless if the Java classes are generated from XML Schema or whatever.

Comment: @laune thank you very much! excuse my ignorance.  I had changed the package of the generated classes. If classes are in the package generated the problem was solved. I tried to wsimpor with -p but I get the error `[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.`    How I can move the classes generated another package?

Answer (score 0):

Don't fiddle with generated code unless you know what you are doing, and then you won't. Here's what I propose to solve the *original* problem.

1. If you can tweak the xjc invocation, option `-p` would do the trick. (If the wsimport option `-p` should have the same effect I don't know what went wrong. The argument must be a valid *Java* package name, not an OS path.)
2. You might define the namespace to reflect the package name, use `simic.soap.generated.repositorio.repositorioxds` instead of RepositorioXDS.
3. Or you can customize the XML Schema by adding a customization statement defining the package name:

Don't forget to add the jaxb namespace prefix definition to `<xs:schema>`, and the JAXB version.

```
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
```